# Decrypting Connection String Throwing Not enough storage available to process the command

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5

I succesfully imported an RSAkeyProvider from production to local machine. Then I tried to decrypt the connectionstring, but I am getting following error..

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -pdf  "connectionStrings" D:\
Decrypting configuration section...
Failed to decrypt using provider 'RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider'. Error mess
age from the provider: Not enough storage is available to process this command.
 (D:\web.config line 9)

Not enough storage is available to process this command.

Failed!

Please help, I am tried googling all day but found no solution

Comment: Are both production and your local machine bit using iis 7.5 ?  and are they both 32/64 bit ?

Comment: Did you try to run the command as administrator?

Comment: Also check if you have this error in Widows System Event log:
Event ID : XXXX
Source : XXX
Description: The Server's configuration parameter "IRPStackSize" is too small for the server to use a local device. Please increase the value of this parameter.

Comment: I ran that command as admin.. I am no longer with that company to try it. Thanks for the udpate, will try if the issue comes up in my future :)

Answer (score 2):

According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) link, your code should be like this

```
aspnet_regiis -pd "connectionStrings" -app "/SampleApplication"
```

I noticed you used a -pdf instead of a -pd

Comment: -pdf option is used If I pass the Path where config file resides.I tried the command you mentioned, but it is throwing same error.